# Joomla: how to load JTable-element with LIKE-condition

Tags: sql, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using the following code to load a categorys record:

```
    $res = JTable::getInstance('category');
    $res->load(array('id' => $catid));
```

Now I would like to load the record based on its title which whould be matched against a SQL LIKE-pattern - is it possible to do this in a simple way with JTable, or do I need $dbo?

Comment: @fititnt is correct JTable load a single record at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Far as I know JTable is made to be simple and carry only **one element at a time**, and through the primary key. If you really want something more advanced, I recomend that you use JDatabaseQuery way.

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all articles for users who have a username which starts with 'a'.
// Order it by the created date.
$query
    ->select(array('a.*', 'b.username', 'b.name'))
    ->from('#__content AS a')
    ->join('INNER', '#__users AS b ON (a.created_by = b.id)')
    ->where('b.username LIKE \'a%\'')
    ->order('a.created DESC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

In your case, instead of "$db->loadObjectList();" you can use "$db->loadObject();" for load just one item.

---

**Source:**
http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/3.1